# How to add multiple email ids into a text field (like facebook privacy setting) and convert the email id list into comma separated list?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using **PHP, jQuery(jquery-1.9.1.min.js and jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js), Bootstap framework(Bootstrap v3.0.0), AJAX,** etc. for my website.

Now at one place I want user to be able to enter multiple email ids into a HTML textfield. It should happen like facebook privacy setting. Following is the screenshot of what I expect to achieve.

[image]

From the above image I want the text field to behave like from the "Don't share this with" section. The only difference is here names are getting displayed and I want to add email ids. No auto populate functionality is needed like Facebook.

When user will submit the form then the comma separated list of entered email ids should be sent to the respective method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one of those libraries will help you:

- [jQuery Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)
- [Taggle.js](http://sean.is/poppin/tags)

Comment: actually I don't want to offer auto complete functionality. The plugin you are suggesting is working only for the values contained in auto-populate list. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Yes, you can checkout "Taggle.js" above. Use commas to separate list items.

Comment: Taggle.js has got exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your help though.